# Use powershell to look up 'net user' on other domains?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

What I am looking to do is to

```
net user user1 /DOMAIN
```

However, I'd like to do it for a domain that the computer ISN'T joined to but has access to.

Users are spread into DOMAIN1 and DOMAIN2. The computer I would run it from is joined to DOMAIN1 but would look up users on DOMAIN2.

Is this possible in/with Powershell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
Get-ADUser "user1" -Server "DC_of_other_domain"
```

Comment: I suppose I should have specified that this is Powershell 1.0. Do I need to get anything on top of that?

Comment: nevermind, it's v2.0 - upon further reading I need to have RSAT installed on my Windows 7 box...and the remote server needs to have webservices running.

Comment: COOOL thanks.
FYI:
you can search list of the domain controllers via this command `nslookup -type=any %userdnsdomain%.`